# Negative momentum arguments in Feynman amplitude

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors

I encountered the below Feynman amplitude with Dirac spinors and photon vectors that have negative momentum arguments:

$$M=\epsilon^\alpha_r(-k)\bar\nu_{s'}(-\vec p')( ie\gamma_\beta) iS_F(p-k)ie\gamma_\alpha u_s(\vec p)\epsilon^\beta_{r'}(-k')$$

where $p,p',k,k'$ are the momenta of the incoming/outgoing particles.

I am trying to express this in terms of spinors/vectors with positive momenta arguments, i.e. something like

$$M \sim \epsilon^\alpha_r(k)\bar\nu_{s'}(\vec p')( ie\gamma_\beta) iS_F(p-k)ie\gamma_\alpha u_s(\vec p)\epsilon^\beta_{r'}(k')$$

For the photon vectors $\epsilon^\alpha_r(k)$, the relation between positive and negative momenta is just
$$\epsilon^\alpha_r(k)=\epsilon^\alpha_r(-k)$$

As for the Dirac spinor $\nu_s(\vec p)$, we have the definitions in the chiral basis as
$$\nu_s(\vec p) =\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{p_\mu \sigma^\mu} \eta_s \\ -\sqrt{p_\mu \bar\sigma^\mu} \eta_s  \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\nu_s(-\vec p) =\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{p_\mu \bar\sigma^\mu} \eta_s \\ -\sqrt{p_\mu \sigma^\mu} \eta_s  \end{bmatrix}$$

How can I relate $\nu_s(\vec p) $ to $\nu_s(-\vec p) $? I don't know how to do this as the $\sigma^\mu $ and $\bar \sigma^\mu$ matrices have switched places in these two definitions.

Comment: Is the minus sign not just a way of writing the momentum of an antiparticle? Does it make sense to write $v_s(p^\prime)$ in this context?

Comment: @nomeruk I am not sure. If it helps, I arrived at this expression by trying to derive equation 12.45 in Mandl Shaw's QFT book (pg. 256), starting from equation 12.36 and substituting in the result of equation 12.44.